# Why side time mark goes back to top when hovering event FullCalendar Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar Angular library and i'm facing a problem with the side time mark.
When I hover over the calendar, the mark is at the right place (black cross represents where my cursor is):

[image]

But when i'm hovering the event, the mark goes back to the top of the calendar :
[image]

Here is the css which change the color :

```
tr:hover td:first-of-type {
   background-color: #64B5F6;
}
```

Like I can't share the code of the calendar here, I'm only asking for reasons about this behaviour which could help me to resolve this.

Comment: You must have some other CSS involved as well I think, because the CSS you've shown doesn't come close to creating the behaviour shown in your screenshots - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/ExKyOPV . Please provide enough code to reproduce the problem accurately. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah i forgot a part of css. Like the demo is a fullcalendar js, mine is with angular, the classes used are different (i don't know why) so i had to find a way to reproduce a similar behaviour. I found one, if you replace the code 
`tr:hover td:first-of-type {
   background-color: #64B5F6;
} `
by
`.fc-timegrid-body tr:hover td:first-of-type {
   background-color: #64B5F6;
} `
you will have a similar behaviour. That's not exactly the same but it ilustrates the problem. When you hover the event, all the left side is colored whereas when not, it works

Comment: That's because the events are overlaid on top of the table rows using positioning, they are not actually inside the row or cell element

Comment: Is it the reason why when I drag/drop or resize an event, i'm brought back to the top of the calendar if i have scrolled the calendar ?

Comment: No it wouldn't affect that directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, it seems because you didn't post an answer in this topic but comments instead, I can't mark this topic as resolved (because you told me why I had this behaviour and that's what i searched). Can you post your comment as an answer so that i mark this topic as resolved thanks to your answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the events are overlaid on top of the table rows using positioning, they are not actually inside the row or cell element. I don't know of a workaround for that.